# Combining multiple MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So, I have this query in PHP which is working as intended:

```
SELECT files.ID, 
       files.Name,
       files.Downloads, 
       if (dlratings.userID IS NULL,0,r.vote) AS has_voted
FROM files
LEFT JOIN dlratings
   ON (files.ID = dlratings.fileID AND dlratings.userID = $userID)
WHERE files.Temporary != 1 AND files.Type = $type AND files.Cat_1 = $cat_1 
ORDER BY files.rating DESC, files.DateOrder DESC
```

Now comes my problem: I want to also select the tags with which these selected files are associated. I am using the [toxi method](http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html), meaning I have a table called "tagmap" with the rows `file_id` and `tag_id` and I have the table "tags" with the rows `tag_id` and `tag_name`.

To list the tags I need on a page with only one File, I use this query:

```
SELECT files.Name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag_name ORDER BY tags.tag_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS tags
FROM files
LEFT JOIN tagmap
   ON tagmap.file_id = files.ID
LEFT JOIN tags
   ON tagmap.tag_id = tags.tag_id
WHERE files.ID = $fileID
```

How do I combine the two, so I can show the tags in the list that is provided by the first query?

This is what I tried but it only gives me 1 result:

```
SELECT files.ID, 
       files.Name,
       files.Downloads,
       GROUP_CONCAT(tags.tag_name ORDER BY tags.tag_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS tags
       if (dlratings.userID IS NULL,0,r.vote) AS has_voted
FROM files
LEFT JOIN tagmap
   ON tagmap.file_id = files.ID
LEFT JOIN tags
   ON tagmap.tag_id = tags.tag_id
LEFT JOIN dlratings
   ON (files.ID = dlratings.fileID AND dlratings.userID = $userID)
WHERE files.Temporary != 1 AND files.Type = $type AND files.Cat_1 = $cat_1 
ORDER BY files.rating DESC, files.DateOrder DESC
```

Note that I am calling these querys via php and I use mysqli. I experimented a bit with the `mysqli_multi_query` but I am totally lost on that one too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a GROUP BY files.ID. That might do it?

Comment: Wow, I totally missed that. Thanks a lot. I will accept your answer as soon as I am allowed to :)